# Saving record in a proper way

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, thymeleaf

I have a problem with saving records to DB with Spring-Mvc and Thymeleaf.
When I click "Update" button on record, to enter the update form (included beneath), all values are in place correctly, but, when I want to subbmit, an error occur. There is no any stacktrace in console, only error in web page, that I am not able to solve.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{maltId}")
public ModelAndView showMalt(@PathVariable("maltId") Long maltId) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("malt/malt-show");
        mav.addObject(maltService.findById(maltId));
        return mav;
}

@GetMapping("/{maltId}/edit")
public String initUpdateMaltForm(@PathVariable("maltId") Long maltId, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("malt", maltService.findById(maltId));
        return VIEWS_MALT_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
    }

@PostMapping("/{maltId}/edit") 
public String processUpdateMaltForm(@Valid Malt malt, BindingResult result, @PathVariable("maltId") Long maltId) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return VIEWS_MALT_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
        } else {
            malt.setId(maltId);
            Malt savedMalt = maltService.save(malt);
            return "redirect:/malt/" + savedMalt.getId();
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
@Column(name="malt_name")
private String maltName;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
private Producer producer;

@Column(name="malt_filling")
private int maltFilling;

@Column(name="malt_ebc")
private int maltEbc;

@Column(name="malt_usage")
private String maltUsage;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="country_id")
private Country country;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="malts")
private Set<Batch> batches;
```

This is the view:

```
<body>  
    <form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{/malt/}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
            <label>Malt name:</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{maltName}" />
                <label>Producer:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{producer.producerName}" />

                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{country.id}">
                    <option value="0">Select country</option>
                    <option th:each="country : ${countries}"
                        th:value="${country?.id}"
                        th:text="${country?.countryName}">
                        </option>
                </select>

                <label>Malt filling:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltFilling}" />

                <label>Malt usage:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltUsage}" />

                <label>Malt EBC:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltEbc}" />


                <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

When I hit `Submit` button, I get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 15 22:46:22 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I have tried couple of different approaches, but nothing helps, and since there is no stacktrace in console, I have no idea what is wrong here.

Link to repo: https://github.com/fangirsan/maruszka-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No stack trace 404 normally indicates that there is no mapping. Since you have, potentially, provided only a part of your `Controller` I assume that the causation for this is the code in your view right here:

```
<form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{/malt/}" method="post">
```

The action takes to `("/malt/")`, however, your controller has not got mapping for this?! 
I expect that this should fix it:

```
  <form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{${'/' + malt.id + '/edit'}}" method="post">
```

> Update

Had a look at your controller and you have the following annotations on your class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/malt")
public class MaltController{..
```

`@RequestMapping("/malt")` will now make your path to save `../malt/{id}/edit'`. The code below now should work:

```
 <form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{${'/malt/' + malt.id + '/edit'}}" method="post">
```

---

> On using "**@{${...}}**"

@{} is a link variable, contents within this tag will be appended to the applications root context, e.g., at Stack Overflow `@{'/posts'}` would result with `https://stackoverflow.com/posts`

The ${} is a variable expression which will return a `String` or the object's `.toString()` value.

If we want to pass a variable within `@{}` link variable we must include the `${}` variable within it, thus resulting in :

```
@{${'/hope/this/helps' + yourVariable}}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem - link to whole repo in updated post.

Comment: I will try today, in few hours. I will let you know if it is working.

Comment: Yes, your solution worked as a charm, thank you for your help. Can I ask you to briefly explain why I need to use `"@{${ ... }}` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot again, now I understand why it didn't work.